# Get viewable rectangle of IE browser

Tags: java, .net, windows, internet-explorer

In Java how do you I get handle of IE browser and get the rectangle of the browser area? In .Net I was able to accomplish this using [UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327.aspx).

This is the code I had done in .net

```
AutomationElement element = AutomationElement.RootElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children,
    new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, browserTitle+" - Windows Internet Explorer"));
element = element.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children,
    new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ClassNameProperty, "Frame Tab"));
element = element.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants,
    new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ClassNameProperty, "TabWindowClass"));

BrowserRect = element.Current.BoundingRectangle;
```

Is there a way to do a similar thing using java and get the rectangle of the browser area?

Comment: Since you have a working solution for .NET, you might call that from Java.

Comment: how would i that .net that from java? I really have not working too much with java

Comment: I don't know - I've never worked with .Net or natives.  I just know it is possible.  Wait a second..  One very hackish way to get a result is to have the .Net dump the information to the standard output stream.  Run the native from Java using a `ProcessBuilder` then read and parse the output.  But I am sure there are better interfaces possible between Java and natives than reading the output.